# Javascript: Taking values from a textbox and adding it to the divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have been racking my brain on how to add the a different value from the text box to a different div. So div1 gets the first thing the user typed, div2 gets the second, div3 gets the third, and so on.  Everytime a user presses the "Add" button whatever the user typed will be added to one of the Div's above it. Right now I have it to where by pressing "Add" the value of the textbox is put in the first div. How do I create a function that will allow the user to add values to other divs. I assume you need a for loop but I do not know how to tackle it.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newTicket2.0.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>


<div id="colorme" style = "cursor:pointer" onClick= "highlightLink()"><p id   = "doubleStuff" ondblclick = "dubleStuff()">check this out</p></div>
<div id="colorme2" style = "cursor:pointer" onClick= "highlightLink2()"><p id = "doubleStuff2" ondblclick = "dubleStuff2()">check this out</p></div>

<p id = "putstuff"></p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id = "workInfo1" style = "cursor:pointer"><p id = "addingInfo"></p>  </div>
<div id = "workInfo12" style = "cursor:pointer"><p id = "addingInfo1"></p>    </div>
<div id = "workInfo13" style = "cursor:pointer"><p id = "addingInfo2"></p></div>
<div id = "workInfo14" style = "cursor:pointer"><p id = "addingInfo3"></p></div>
<br>
<br>
<textarea name="workInfo" cols="60" rows="5" id="workInfo">
</textarea>
<button type = "button" name = "addWorkInfo" id = "addWorkInfo" onclick =    "workInfoAdd()">Add</button>
<script>
function highlightLink(){
var highL = document.getElementById('colorme');
var highL2 = document.getElementById('colorme2');
highL.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
highL2.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
};
function highlightLink2(){
var highL = document.getElementById('colorme');
var highL2 = document.getElementById('colorme2');
highL.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
highL2.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
function dubleStuff(){
var x = "You double clicked it";
document.getElementById('putstuff').innerHTML = x;
};
function dubleStuff2(){
var x = "different stuff";
document.getElementById('putstuff').innerHTML = x;
};
function workInfoAdd(){
var z = document.getElementById('workInfo')
document.getElementById('addingInfo').innerHTML = z.value

    if (z.value === null || z.value === ""){
    alert('please enter work info');
    }
    else {
    z.value = "";
   }
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Would something like this work.

```
  var i = document.getElementById('addingInfo');
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  document.getElementbyId('workInfo').value = i //or some other variable that specifies the "adding info"
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. As stated above after everytime the user presses ADD, the value they put into the text box will be added to the subsequent div. First add goes to first div, second goes to second div and so on.

Comment: Think about creating checkpoints. So when the first time the add button is pressed increment a variable by 1 or something like that, then you can use conditional statements like if-else and say that if variable = 1 then push value to div 1, if var = 2 push to div 2 and so on. or instead of incrementing you can use booleans and change them to true or false once the add button is clicked. Hope this helps.

Comment: you want to add the text in the <p> tag inside the div right?

Comment: yes thats correct. Currently playing around with for loops trying to do create those checkpoints referenced in the comment above

Comment: @zombiedude789 see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably write something like this:

```js
var divIndex = 0;

function workInfoAdd() {

  var z = document.getElementById('workInfo');
  var p = document.getElementById('addingInfo' + (divIndex || ''));
  if (!p) {
    return;
  }

  if (z.value === null || z.value === "") {
    alert('please enter work info');
  } else {
    p.innerHTML = z.value;
    z.value = "";
  }

  divIndex++;
};
```

```html
<div id="workInfo1" style="cursor:pointer;border: dotted 1px">
  <p id="addingInfo"></p>
</div>
<div id="workInfo12" style="cursor:pointer;border: dotted 1px">
  <p id="addingInfo1"></p>
</div>
<div id="workInfo13" style="cursor:pointer;border: dotted 1px">
  <p id="addingInfo2"></p>
</div>
<div id="workInfo14" style="cursor:pointer;border: dotted 1px">
  <p id="addingInfo3"></p>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<textarea name="workInfo" cols="60" rows="5" id="workInfo">
</textarea>
<button type="button" name="addWorkInfo" id="addWorkInfo" onclick="workInfoAdd()">Add</button>
```

Additionally you can use document.querySelector() for more advanced matching of elements ex.

```
var p = document.querySelector('.workInfo' + divIndex + ' > p.addingInfo' + divIndex);
```

Comment: appreciate the help, quick question though could you explain what the if(!p) is doing. I get that it is not p but what exactly does that do?

Comment: Every time you press add the divIndex increases by 1, which means after 4 times the function will look for addingInfo4 which you don't have and p will be undefined in this case. I'm adding this check so the function won't throw errors. In this place you can also add code to inject div into the DOM if you need more than 3.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you want. I have added a class for all the p tags which will contain the information after click.

Html

```
<p id = "putstuff"></p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id = "workInfo1" style = "cursor:pointer"><p class ="addingInfo" id = "addingInfo"></p>  </div>
<div id = "workInfo12" style = "cursor:pointer"><p class ="addingInfo" id = "addingInfo1"></p>    </div>
<div id = "workInfo13" style = "cursor:pointer"><p class ="addingInfo" id = "addingInfo2"></p></div>
<div id = "workInfo14" style = "cursor:pointer"><p class ="addingInfo" id = "addingInfo3"></p></div>
<br>
<br>
<textarea name="workInfo" cols="60" rows="5" id="workInfo">
</textarea>
<button type = "button" name = "addWorkInfo" id = "addWorkInfo" onclick ="workInfoAdd()">Add</button>
```

javascript

```
function workInfoAdd()
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('addingInfo');
    for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
    {
        if(elements[i].innerHTML == "")
        {
            elements[i].innerHTML = document.getElementById('workInfo').value;
            document.getElementById('workInfo').value = "";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/okLme061/1/

Comment: Thanks dude, I like how concise it is. how would you clear out the value after adding it to the div though? I was playing around with it and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @zombiedude789 which value? text value or div values? I have edited the answer to clear the text value.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code but remember that this solution should be used if you are going to limit the number of div (i.e only 3 or 4 divs) because if you want unlimited divs you will have to program an if-else statement for each possible div:

```
// Declare variable
var x = 0;

function workInfoAdd(){
// Increment
  x++

// Check increment value
  if(x == 1){
      var z = document.getElementById('workInfo')
      document.getElementById('addingInfo').innerHTML = z.value

         if (z.value === null || z.value === ""){
               alert('please enter work info');
         }
  else { z.value = "";}
     }

// Check increment value
else if(x == 2){
      var z = document.getElementById('workInfo')
      document.getElementById('addingInfo1').innerHTML = z.value

         if (z.value === null || z.value === ""){
         alert('please enter work info');
       }

 else {z.value = "";}
}
  // Check increment value
  else if(x == 3){
        var z = document.getElementById('workInfo')
        document.getElementById('addingInfo2').innerHTML = z.value

if (z.value === null || z.value === ""){
        alert('please enter work info');
}
else {z.value = "";}
  }
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6byvuzxf/

I have created check points as mentioned in my comment before.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help, learned something new. Definetly gonna keep this in mind for future projects.